# How to program spare key for Toyota Premio 260

Tags: toyota, key, car, smartkey

I have a Toyota Premio 260 model vehicle, anybody please help me to pair my extra smart key to my vehicle.

your help highly appreciated.

Comment: What year is your car ... could make a difference.

Comment: manifacture year is 2008.

Comment: How do I add a second key fob to my 2008 Premio / Allion

Answer (score 4):

I found this information on a [Toyota forum](http://www.fjcruiserforums.com/forums/stereo-electronics-electrical/109652-step-step-how-program-key-fob-new-existing.html). It is from Toyota TSB dated November 9, 2007 (TSB#EL009-07). It works with a lot of different Toyota models for 2007-2008 and ***may* work for yours as well**. (**NOTE:** If it doesn't work, *let me know* and I'll delete this answer). It appears fairly complicated and time critical (time during/between steps needs to be done accurately).

Begin With:

Driver's door open and unlocked & key out of ignition

1. Insert and remove the key from the ignition switch 2 times within 5 seconds

**NOTE:** Steps 2 and 3 should be performed within 40 seconds

2. Close and open the driver's door TWICE.
3. Insert the key into the ignition and remove it.

**NOTE:** Steps 4-6 should be performed within 40 seconds

4. Close and open the driver's door TWICE
5. Insert the key into the ignition
6. Close the door
7. Turn the ignition switch from "LOCK" to "ON" and back to "LOCK" at about 1 second intervals to select the desired mode from the list below:

```
    1 time for ADD mode
    2 times for REWRITE mode
    3 times for CONFIRMATION mode
    5 times for PROHIBITION mode
```

8. Remove the key from the ignition
9. To confirm your mode selection, the power locks will now cycle "lock" to "unlock" a number of times corresponding to your key cycles in step 7.

**NOTE:** If CONFIRMATION or PROHIBITION modes have been selected, opening the door will complete the procedure.

10. For ADD or REWRITE modes, do the following within 40 seconds of Door Lock confirmation:

**A -** Press both transmitter LOCK and UNLOCK buttons simultaneously between 1 and 1.5 seconds and release.

**B -** Within 3 seconds of step A, press the transmitter LOCK button from more than 1 second and release.

If the transmitter has been successfully programmed, the power locks will cycle "lock" to "unlock" once at this time.

If there are problems with the transmitter or the procedure up to this point, the locks will cycle twice. If this occurs, verify that you have received the correct transmitter, and then repeat the above procedure.

**C -** If multiple remotes are to be reprogrammed, repeat steps A and B

11. Open to driver's door to conclude programming mode
12. If you make an error during the programming mode, turn the ignition key to "ON" and back to "LOCK" to erase entered steps.

This procedure works for the following;

- 2000 - 2005 Celica
- 2001 - 2003 Prius
- 2001 - 2005 ECHO
- 2001 - 2007 Highlander
- 2001 - 2008 RAV4
- 2002 - 2006 Camry
- 2003 - 2008 Avalon, Corolla and Matrix
- 2004 - 2008 Sienna and Solara
- 2005 - 2008 Tacoma
- 2007 - 2008 FJ Cruiser and Yaris

Comment: Hi .. you cannot proceed the 1st step since there is no ignition switch/ or holder for Premio 260 version.